# Entity Framework Code First - Setting Foreign Key / Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, data-annotations

I like to reference to a specific entry in a database. Is there a data annotation, which I could use
E.g.

```
public class Address
{
public int CityId {get; set;}
}

public class City
{
public int id {get; set;}
}
```

So the Address.CityId references the City.id.

And how can I reference to Table Columns via data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link .

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

in that read Topic : **The Key Attribute**

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called One-To-One entity mapping. You can create navigation property in your `Address` class as follows:

```
public class Address
{
[Key]
public int AddressID {get;set;}
public int CityID {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("CityID")]
public City City {get;set;}
}

public class City
{
[Key]
public int CityID {get; set;}
}
```

Add `ForeignKey` attribute to your navigation property to create mapping through foreign key. And do not forget to define key attributes in each EF model.

More details on Entity Framework home page: [Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)